# Django + Celery 4 wrong settings

Tags: python, django, rabbitmq, celery

I'm using Django 1.10 and Celery 4.

I found leaks in Celery's Documentation :(

The worker configuration is well done and It run fine (I can see the worker connected in RabbitMQ webmin). But my tasks can't connect to RabbitMQ to publish their messages.

**settings.py**

```
CELERY_BROKER_URL = 'amqp://dev:dev@localhost/dev_virtualhost'
CELERY_ACCEPT_CONTENT = ['json']
CELERY_TASK_SERIALIZER = 'json'
CELERY_RESULT_SERIALIZER = 'json'
```

**celery.py**

```
from __future__ import absolute_import
import os
from celery import Celery

os.environ.setdefault('DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE', 'settings')

app = Celery('dev_app')
app.config_from_object('django.conf:settings', namespace='CELERY')

app.autodiscover_tasks()

@app.task(bind=True)
def debug_task(self):
    print('Request: {0!r}'.format(self.request))
```

**tasks.py**

```
from celery import shared_task

@shared_task(queue='data_to_write')
def test_task(data):
    open('/tmp/test', 'w').write(data)
```

From Django's Shell I run this code and fail :(

`test_task.delay('hello world')`

AccessRefused: (0, 0): (403) ACCESS_REFUSED - Login was refused using authentication mechanism AMQPLAIN. For details see the broker logfile.

In the RabbitMQ logs I see that credentials are guest:guest, no dev:dev like I wrote in the settings.py.

Where is my error? Thanks

Comment: Are you using a result backend? If yes, how is it configured?

Comment: Can we see your RabbitMQ configuration?

Comment: I'm also seeing this.  Obviously curious if you solved it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution consists in rename `celery.py` to `celery_app.py` to avoid auto import.

Then you must execute celery in this way:
`celery --app=PACKAGE.celery_app:app worker`

PACKAGE is the module (folder) where you put the celery_app.py